# Ajax submit form and store in PHP/WordPress session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, session

This is my form:

```
<form id="sessie_datum">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Klik hier om een datum te kiezen" name="wapbk_hidden_date" value="">
    <input type="submit" value"submit">
</form>
```

I submit this form with AJAX into my root folder of WordPress in a file called datum.php

My jQuery function is like this:

```
 $("form#sessie_datum").submit(function() {
        var str = jQuery("#sessie_datum").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://testnieuw.skihal.com/datum.php',
            data: $("#sessie_datum").serialize(),
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function() {
                alert('Gelukt!');
            }        
        });
     return false;        
});
```

After clicking the submit button I get the alert so it goes to the file.

My next question is what needs to be in the datum.php file to get the date which is filled in the datepicker?
After that I want to store it as a variable in the WordPress session, is that possible.

EDIT:

My datum.php now has this:

```
   <?php

session_start();
$_SESSION["chosen_date"] = $_POST['wapbk_hidden_date'];

$foo = "Test";
$_SESSION['foo'] = $foo;

?>
```

My functions.php has this:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['foo'];
echo session_id();
```

Comment: Put the following in `datum.php` and check the response in your browsers developer console: `<?php print_r($_POST);`. It will show you which variables are available and it's easy to pick the right one that way.

Comment: Jacob, in the response in the console I see `Array ( [wapbk_hidden_date] => 2019-02-01 )`. So it should all work. Can you put in datum.php `print_r($_SESSION);` (after session start) ?

Comment: Hi, I only see this: `https://ibb.co/xhzFz5s`
By the way I added `print_r($_SESSION);` to datum.php

Comment: Seems like you have changed more now, but the date is there, I don't understand your problem anymore, everything works :-)

Comment: Hi if I navigate to URL/datum.php I see it works. But the only thing now is that for example I want to print '2019-02-01' in any other file of my site. How can that be done?

Comment: Do it this way: `echo htmlentities($_SESSION["chosen_date"]);`. You should use `htmlentities()` to prevent injection of unwanted characters in your output. Everytime you want to access session data (read or write, both) you also need `session_start();`, don't forget that.

Comment: Thanks man! It is working. Searched a long time for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the date using ajax in datum.php. how to get in datum.php i total depends on you ajax 'type' which is POST or GET.

```
If type = POST
$_SESSION["chosen_date"] = $_POST['wapbk_hidden_date'];

if Type = GET
$_SESSION['chosen_date'] = $_GET['wapbk_hidden_date']

echo $_SESSION['chosen_date'];
```

Comment: then 'data' will be a variable which can be called in my functions.php file?

Comment: here data is the temp variable used to store value on session...you can use it on any page

Comment: Hi,

My datum.php is now like:

`<?php
$_SESSION["chosen_date"] = $_POST['wapbk_hidden_date'];
?>`


In my functions.php I have this:


`$call_date = $_POST['chosen_date'];
echo $call_date;`

Then it echos this:
Undefined index: chosen_date in <b>/var/www/vhosts/skihal.com/testnieuw.skihal.com/wp-content/themes/skihal-child/functions.php on line 11

Comment: You have to use $_SESSION['chosen_date'] instead of $_POST['chosen_date']...bcz your form posting 'wapbk_hidden_date' which you are storing into 'chosen_date session' so you have to access chosen_date session...check edited answer

Comment: Hi, check my edited question.
This is how it looks right now. 
Still getting an echo: undefined variable: _SESSION in /var/www/vhosts/skihal.com/testnieuw.skihal.com/wp-content/themes/skihal-child/functions.php on line 11

Do I need to start a session in datum.php?

Comment: have you added session_start();

Comment: you have to declare session_start(); on every page ow declare in common file before using $_SESSION

Comment: Hi, I updated my code for testing to call a SESSION variable. functions.php is loaded on every page so why can 'Test' not being called on every page?

Comment: what is 'Test'? 1st you have to add statement session_start(); on every page or you have add it in the file which is already included on all pages ... then only can able to fetch the session data on every page

Comment: 'Test' is a variable I made to test if I can even echo anything from `datum.php` file what I stored in the SESSION. `session_start();` is in my `functions.php` which is loaded in every page.

Comment: you are setting $foo = 'test' in datum.php file.when you execute url/datum.php that time you $foo and $_SESSION['foo'] will be set then only it will be echoing "Test"

Answer (score -1):

in datum.php

make it as a session like

`session_start();`

`if(isset($_REQUEST['wapbk_hidden_date'])) {`
`$_SESSION['wapbk_hidden_date']=$_REQUEST['wapbk_hidden_date'];`
`}`